# Using one time series to predict another (unevenly spaced) with Python

Tags: python, time-series

My goal is to find a way to test whether the time serie (red) can explain or predict the time serie (blue).

I have never worked with this kind of times series which are measured on different times/dates.

I would like any ideas or suggestions to set me on the path of approaching this problem.

I am not asking for a certain code but just methods and ways for approaching this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about get correlation between Red and Blue.
Or you can check correlation between **Blue +/- some days** and **Red**

Below link seems good example regarding time-series prediction
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-predict-a-time-series-part-1-6d7eb182b540